# Querying Date Range and Feature Service ID in gis.content.search

Tags: python, arcgis-online

I am trying to use Python to export data from ArcGIS Online within a specific date range while also using a specific feature service.

I have been able to get this to work successfully:

```
num_items = 3
query_string = "type:Feature Service, id:1234a5678b91011c12131415d1617"
items = gis.content.search(query=query_string, max_items=num_items, sort_field='modifed', sort_order='desc')
```

but this will download the entire feature service as a file geodatabase

I have tried various version of something like this:

```
num_items = 3
query_string = "modified:[1654133321 TO 1655861321] AND type:Feature Service, id:1234a5678b91011c12131415d1617"
items = gis.content.search(query=query_string, max_items=num_items, sort_field='modifed', sort_order='desc')
print(str(len(items)) + " items will be backed up to " + folder_path +". See the list below:")
```

with the response of "0 items will be backed up to" when I know there have been several hundred items within that time period.

I can't seem to find any examples of this type of syntax to try to get this to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify the "no luck"? Does it raise an exception? Return an error message? Please [Edit] the Question.